# Javascript pub/sub implementation works for functions, but not objects' methods

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to implement a simple Pub/Sub object in javascript, and here's my code:

```
var PubSub=new function(){
    this.subscriptions=[];
    this.subscribe=function(topic,callback){
        if(!this.subscriptions[topic]){
            this.subscriptions[topic]=[];
        }
        this.subscriptions[topic].push(callback);
    }
    this.unsubscribe=function(topic,callback){
        if(this.subscriptions[topic]){
            for(var i=this.subscriptions[topic].length-1;i>=0;i--){
                if(this.subscriptions[topic][i]==callback){
                    this.subscriptions[topic].splice(i,1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    this.publish=function(topic,data){
        if(this.subscriptions[topic]){
            for(var i=this.subscriptions[topic].length-1;i>=0;i--){
                this.subscriptions[topic][i](data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, subscribing a simple function, and then publishing some stuff works great:

```
PubSub.subscribe("test",print); //print: shell function
PubSub.publish("test","hello"); //print outputs "hello"
```

But, subscribing a function, which is an object's method doen't work:

```
var a=new function(){
    this.c=0;
    this.i=function(x){
        this.c+=x;
    }
}
PubSub.subscribe("test",a.i);
PubSub.publish("test",17);
a.c; //is still 0
```

I also tried using apply (assuming data is an array):

```
PubSub.publish=function(topic,data){
    ...
        this.subscriptions[topic][i].apply(this,data);
    ...
}
```

It doesn't work either, though I believe it's not the same problem: I think the `this` object passed by apply overrides the `this` object of `a`, and therefore `a.i` tries to set `PubSub.a` instead of `a.a`...

Comment: It should also be noted that: this.subscriptions=[]; should instead be this.subscriptions={}; based on how you are using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass `a.i` to `PubSub.subscribe`, you've "detached" the `i` function from `a`, its invocation context. Either use an anonymous function to maintain the binding:

```
PubSub.subscribe("test", function (x) { a.i(x); });
```

or use [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to preserve `a` as `this` whenever `i` is called:

```
PubSub.subscribe("test", a.i.bind(a));
```

N.B. `Function.bind` is not supported in all browsers, so you'll want to [use the shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility).

Comment: Ok thanks, I see why my example didn't work! When I use the anonymous function, `unsubscribe` doesn't work anymore, but declaring the function first, so it has a name, and then passing it to `subscribe` solves that problem...