# Javascript methods: this & that

Tags: javascript, object, methods, this

First question here.

I'm trying Javascript objects. Here's my code:

```
function main(){
    document.onkeydown = hero.keyListener;
    hero.move();
    hero.counter(); 
}
var hero = {
    dx: undefined,
    dy: undefined,
    keyListener: function (e) {
        this.dy = 100;
    },  
    move: function () {
        this.dx = 80;
    },
    counter: function() {
        document.getElementById("dxcounter").innerHTML = "Dx: "+ this.dx + " Dy: "+ this.dy;
    }   
};
```

The move method updates `this.dx` but keyListener does not update `this.dy` when a key is pressed.

It works if I change keyListener like this:

```
keyListener: function (e) {
    that = hero;
    that.dy = 100;
},
```

Why does the move method work for `this` but not the keyListener?

Comment: It's the same answer as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10107401/139010).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, `this` is not tied down to an object by default; it is set by context. In this case, `this` will be `document`. One way to fix this is to bind the function such that `this` will always be `hero`:

```
document.onkeydown = hero.keyListener.bind(hero);
```

<sup>Note: [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is only available in more recent browsers.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The `this` operator in JavaScript doesn't always follow the scoping rules you would expect.

This article will help to explain what is going on: http://unschooled.org/2012/03/understanding-javascript-this/